# Two different classes inherit from the same super class in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, oop, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I have a custom UITableViewHeaderFooterView class and a custom UITableViewCell class. These two classes share some methods and variables. I think it's better to create a super class for the shared methods and variables, instead of coping things around. But these two custom classes already have different superclasses.

What's the best practice to do this?

Comment: They're fundamentally different objects (a cell and a view, basically). They should not descend from anything more common than UIView.  There's no point in sharing state just because the objects look similar.

Comment: Maybe you are right. I thought maybe there is a pattern for it.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a category on UIView with checks for what class is actually using them, but it won't really address state. 
State for these should probably be in the delegate.

You could also create a protocol, but both will still need to implement.

Beyond that I can imagine they could share the same delegate.

Answer (score 0):

What you want here is Multiple Inheritance, which is not supported (directly) by Objective C.

> Protocols address the absence of multiple inheritance (MI) to some
> extent: Technically, protocols are equivalent to MI for purely
> "abstract" classes (see the answer on `Protocols' below).

There are three other options which you can use:

> Protocols
> (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProtocols.html)
>
> Composition
> (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW15)
>
> Message Forwarding (and specifically Forwarding and Multiple
> Inheritance)
> (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html)